# Is there a precompiled version of the CRM4 plugin registration tool?

Tags: dynamics-crm-4

Question says it all. Customer needs to register a DLL, doesn't have Visual Studio so can't compile the plug-in tool. I don't have a CRM4 system to link the source code to so I can't compile it either.

I just need the plugin tool already compiled to allow the customer to install a plugin DLL.

Comment: Have you actually tried to search for it?

Comment: I'd love to know why my question was marked down. Is it perhaps because I wasn't as successful searching for the file as @ccellar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a precompiled version available on the msdn archive site

http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/crmplugin/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=2010